# How can I make stubble facial hair in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do you add stubble facial hair in blender cycles to a character? I have tried using the particle system for hair but it just makes uneven patches of hair that is the skin color of my character.

Answer (score 3):

By default particles will use the same material as the object they are emitted from. To use a custom material for your particles you need to [add another material](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html#creating-a-new-material) to your object -

[image]

then assign that material to your particles in the particles render settings.

[image: Particle settings]

Comment: Thanks, do you know how you would make the hair stubble? Like really short, I have tried to make it stubble but when it renders it is just big patches of hair. I have tried messing with particle settings and googling it but there seems to be nothing for making it stubble.

Comment: Try a small hair length around `0.02` [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsyKhJ-BOJk&index=3&list=PLA48198363B0728CD) covers a short beard.